# Scattering of light rays off a corrugated surface

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

I am currently facing the following problem:

Suppose I describe the shape of a corrugated surface with a certain function:

\begin{equation}
y_\mathrm{surf}=A\sin(kx); 
\qquad
x\in(-\infty,\infty)
\end{equation}

Further supposing that there is an observer, positioned at a point $P=(x_0,y_0)$ somewhere above the surface. If light rays are arriving at an angle $\theta_i$ with respect to e.g. the $x$ axis and are scattered from the surface, what is the average angle of scattered light rays $\theta_{f,\mathrm{avg}}$ (with respect to e.g. the $x$ axis) the observer will measure at point $P$?

EDIT: Furthermore, suppose that $y_0 \gg A$.

Comment: The answer depends on all the variables of your surface, like length, width, orientation of and distance to the surface, A, k, refractive index and the wavelength of the light. For an accurate answer you need a good 2D or 3D Maxwell simulator.

Comment: Are you aware of existance of any analytical methods/approximations? Thanks.

Comment: RCWA, FDTD are some keywords to search. Analytical approaches require approximation of the surface as perhaps a phas grating. As I said, it depends on a _lot_ if parameters tgat you did not specify.

Comment: For some ranges of the variables, what you describe is a simple sinusoidal diffraction grating.  It can even "scatter" light into just one direction.

Comment: Check out wikipedia on "Lambertian reflectance", this would me a good start.